# Form element inside html element not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have read the documentation and tried all the  possible solution but no gain.

This is my html code

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
$this->Form->button("Continue", ["type" => "button", "class"=>"btn btn-dark btn-theme-colored btn-flat mr-5"]),
array(
'controller' => 'my_controller',
'action' => 'my_action'
));?>
```

I want to have a button inside `<a>` tag but it is outputting the button in '' " tags.

This is what i want

```
<i>
   <button></button>
</i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All special chars will be converted to html entities, unless you disable this behavior, using escape option. Code below should output what you want:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
$this->Form->button("Continue", ["type" => "button", "class"=>"btn btn-dark 
btn-theme-colored btn-flat mr-5"]),
array(
    'controller' => 'my_controller',
    'action' => 'my_action'
),
array(
    'escape' => false
));?>
```

More about HTML helper can be found here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links

Comment: why to use both array ? i mean why i can put escape right after the `action`

Comment: Most HtmlHelper methods take options array as second argument, but HtmlHelper::link() not - second argument in that method is reserved for url. To specify options for link, you need to provide additional array as third argument.